# jenkins builds the same project several times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I'm learning Jenkins, I've configured one simple project that only gets a git repository. 
I click on "Build Now" button, and Jenkins, start a new task, after finished that task, it starts a new task and so.
Is it normal? Isn't supposed that after finishing that task it shouldn't start over? How do I fix it?[image]

Comment: Can you show your configuration script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Build now** is when your project does not have parameters. So users click in the **Build now** button and as nothing is displayed, users perform a click again and again several times in the same **Build now** button.

As a result of this ,Jenkins launch several builds. And if build is so fast, nothing change in the screen.

- A quick fix is put a sleep(milliseconds) in the job in order to delay the build execution and jenkins will show a progress bar:

[image]

- Other fix is configure one dummy parameter like : notes, reason, date, etc so users will be forced to enter the parameter value and preventing quickly clicks in build button.